# How to test connected component using jest?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jestjs

This is my component in react native and all the functionality in the component is working fine.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class ABC extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', backgroundColor: '#ff22ff', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text style={{ color: '#000000' }}>{ this.props.data }</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        data: state.appReducer.hi
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ABC);
```

How can we test a connected component? I am able to test normal component.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, When I made a test for a connected component I followed [this](https://medium.com/netscape/testing-a-react-redux-app-using-jest-and-enzyme-b349324803a9) very useful guide.

Basically you have 2 ways to do this test, but I prefer the way of the component wrapped into Provider. I explain better:

(I suppose that you already know how jest and enzyme work so I skip this part)

First of all you need these dependencies:

```
"react-addons-test-utils" // Not used directly but required as enzyme dependency 
"react-test-renderer" // Used to grab snapshot of DOM tree rendered by React DOM/ React Native components
"redux-mock-store" // Used to mock our Redux store.
```

Then your test:

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
...

describe('Testing ABC connected component',()=>{
const initialState = {data:10}
const mockStore = configureStore()
let store,wrapper

beforeEach(()=>{
    store = mockStore(initialState)
    wrapper = mount( <Provider store={store}><ABC /></Provider> )
})

it('Check Prop matches with initialState', () => {
   expect(wrapper.find(ABC).prop('data')).toEqual(initialState.data)
});

});
```

As you can see, we used `configureStore` from `'redux-mock-store'` to mock a store. Then, we call `mockStore(initialState)` to create the store (with an initialState) that we will pass to the Provider (`<Provider store={store}>`).

Now we have the component wrapped in Provider with a store initialized. Done! Now you can test if the initial status is passed to your component. You can trigger a dispatch with different `data` and verify if the component receive that data... All the test you want to make with your connected component.